# Nested for-loop parallelization in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to parallelize an existing algorithm in spark (in a way that will scale). I've simplified it for the purpose of the question, but it looks something like this:

```
for p in all_p:
    all_q = calculate1(p)

    results_for_p = []
    for q in all_q:
        results_for_p.append(calculate2(q))

    save_results(results_for_p)
```

Basically I have nested for loop with 2 long-running functions I would like to run in parallel. However, the parameters to the nested function `calculate2` are of variable size depending on each `p`.

My attempt was to flatten the input, so that calculate2 runs on all_q and all_p together:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(all_p)
all_q_each_p = rdd.map(calculate1).collect()

# flatten output to something we can parallelize:
all_q_all_p = []
for all_q in all_q_each_p:
    all_q_all_p.append(all_q)

rdd = sc.parallelize(all_q_all_p)
res = rdd.map(calculate2).collect()

# How to do this?? 
collect_and_save_all_results(res)
```

How to write this in a way which will scale well?

Comment: I am not sure we can talk of nested parallelization.

Comment: @thebluephantom I've updated the title to "nested for-loop parallelization"

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the type of problem that `flatMap` solves. `flatMap` resizes the rdd by default.

The code becomes much simpler:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(all_p)

rdd.flatMap(calculate1).map(
    lambda args: calculate2(*args)
).collect()
```